# Laravel 5.7 not sending emails and not showing any error

Tags: laravel-5.7, laravel-mail

I have to run mail function on laravel with google `smtp.gmail.com` or default mail() DRIVER only cant use other methods as client requirement but both not working. I tried everything that I can

I tried smtp.gmail.com and default mail() DRIVER both but no result

**.env file code**

With smtp

```
 MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
 MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
 MAIL_PORT=587
 MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxxxx@gmail.com
 MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxx
 MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

With mail

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=null
MAIL_PORT=null
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Controller code

```
$template_data = EmailTemplate::getEmailTemplateByID($template->id);
                $email_params['verification_code'] = $user->verification_code;
                $email_params['name'] = Helper::getUserName($user->id);
                $email_params['email'] = $user->email;
                Mail::to($user->email)
                    ->send(
                        new GeneralEmailMailable(
                            'verification_code',
                            $template_data,
                            $email_params
                        )
                    );
```

It's not showing any error just showing success message that you are registered or we send recovery email but no email in inbox

Comment: your need to add mail host and mailport as these are requires to send mail

Comment: go through this link https://appdividend.com/2018/03/05/send-email-in-laravel-tutorial/

Comment: in smtp driver i am adding that but in mail driver its null

Comment: pls go through that link that I've give must help you

Comment: working can you post this as answer so I can mark it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add mail host and mailport as these are requires to send mail.

> just go through this link must resolve this issue

https://appdividend.com/2018/03/05/send-email-in-laravel-tutorial/